# LINQ to XSD in Visual Studio 2010 Beta2

Tags: visual-studio, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-xsd

I've been looking around and I was wondering if this is available in VS10 beta2.

So far all I've seen is the Linq to XSD alpha 0.2 preview that works for VS 2008

Comment: For the people unfamiliar with LINQ to XSD, could you provide a link to the alpha preview you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Linq to XSD appears pretty well abandoned.  But its open source, so have at it!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 3 versions now which target .NET Framework 4:

http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/